# Cannot assign MonoBehaviour script to AddMonoBehavioursModifierType array in inspector

Tags: c#, mapbox, mapbox-unity

Like the title implies, i cannot assign a MonoBehaviour to the Array in the inspector window for AddMonoBehavioursModifiersType script. I get an error message saying "Selected object is not a MonoBehaviour type!".

This should be straight forward, as i've seen others do it without problems [(youtube tutorial by mapbox).](https://youtu.be/5EiFB0dZ660?list=PL86WBCjNmqh4VlMzOCOCJrxP_mk6uypcH&t=845) What is the cause?

- Unity version: 2020.3.1f1 LTS

  - Scripting Runtime Version: .NET 2.0
  - Scripting Backend: Mono
  - Api Compatibility Level: .NET 2.0
- Mapbox SDK version: 2.1.1
- The platform you're building to: PC, Mac and Linux standalone
- A description of what you're trying to do: Assign MonoBehaviour script to each rendered gameobject of Map Prefab
- Steps to recreate the bug if appropriate:

1. Create a C# script (right click editor > create > C# Script)
2. create a Mapbox MonoBehaviour Modifier (right click editor > create > mapbox > modifiers > add MonoBehaviours Modifier).
3. Click `+` icon in inspector window for newly created Mapbox Monobehaviour Modifier and assign the newly created C# Script to the Array of name types. Here i get the error message:

> Selected object is not a MonoBehaviour type!

- Links to your logs are also helpful: No logs.

**Edit: Solution: After restarting the computer and Unity, it worked by itself.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple restart of the computer and Unity made it work.